# Django inline set readonly field by condition

Tags: python, django

Looking for something like this:

```
for field in inlinemodel:
    if field.obj.rm.id == '1':
        readonly.append(field.note)
```

Model is:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    rm = models.ForeignKey(Alias)
    note = models.TextField()
```

As you can understand all fields has similar name `rm` and `note` and in browser looks like `note_set-1-note`.

Comment: Do you want to replace your loop for a inline statement ?

Comment: I want to set some fields (by row) to readonly with condition. The problem is that they have got one name `note` for all. If I set `readonly_fields = ('note',)` thay all become readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to set a django **modelform** not a model field to **readonly/disabled**, depending on some statement like `if(condition is true){ dothis(); }`

Step 1.

You first will have to create a new FormField class by **subclassing django.forms.Field**.

You then will have to create a **clean()** function in your overriden form field class and add a conditional statement to it. See below for an example

```
from django import forms.Field 
class MyCustomFormField(forms.Field):
      clean(self):
          if self.instance.is_disabled
               return self.instance.field
          else:
               return self.cleaned_data.get('field')
```

Step 2.

Then in your loop of all fields in you form, when you have your if statement just add this
`modelform.fields['field_1'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` to make the field disabled

`

Comment: Used custom form `__init__` to condition choice. Thanks. BTW fields with `foreignkey` not working properly.